# Flexible array member not getting copied when I make a shallow copy of a struct

Tags: c, struct, shallow-copy, flexible-array-member

I have made a shallow copy a struct I have in the following manner:

```
struct Student{
        char *name;
        int age;
        Courses *list;  //First course (node)
        Student *friends[];   //Flexible array member stores other student pointers
    }Student;

void shallowCopy(const Student *one){
    Student *oneCopy = malloc(sizeof(one) + 20*sizeof(Student*));

    *oneCopy = *one;     <--------------- ERROR POINTS TO THIS LINE
}
```

When I check the first element of the flexible array member it `oneCopy`, it is null. But if I check the first element of the flexible array member in the original struct it prints out the pointer successfully. All the other components of the original struct are copied over like the name and the linked list. It is only the flexible array member that is not getting copied. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You seem to missing some pointers in your code. `oneCopy` looks like it should be `Student *oneCopy` and `friends` looks like it should be `Student *friends[]`.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Yes you are right, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: How do you know the number of elements in the friends array?  I'm expecting to see a count value as another field in the Student struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Trying to use assignment to copy a struct with a flexible array member. From the standard (6.7.2.1):

> The assignment `*s1 = *s2` only copies the member `n` [i.e. the part of the struct that isn't a flexible array]; if any of the array elements are within the first `sizeof (struct s)` bytes of the structure, they might be copied or simply overwritten with indeterminate values.

Basically, when the C compiler sees a struct with a flexible array member, it doesn't know how big it really is, so it treats it as being big enough to hold the other members, plus *possibly* some more:

> In particular, the size of the structure is as if the flexible array member were omitted except that it may have more trailing padding than the omission would imply.

That's what `sizeof(*one)` is, and *that's* the size of what gets copied when you do `*oneCopy = *one;`.

Since you *do* apparently know the size of the entire structure, in order to `malloc` it, just copy that many bytes using `memcpy`. Or if you're concerned that that's somehow unportable (honestly I'm not sure), do the assignment, *then* use a loop to copy each element from `one->friends` to
`oneCopy->friends`.

Comment: I dont think that the issue I have is a space issue. Cause just to test it out, I add the size of 10,000 Student structs. But the pointer is still null.

Comment: @Brandon I never suggested you have a "space issue".

Comment: could you please show me and example of the change you think I should make so I could understand

Comment: `memcpy(oneCopy, one, sizeof(one) + 20*sizeof(Student*))`

Comment: Using pointers in-memory that were all returned by malloc, you should not have portability problems.  All the pointers will be copied and all will be aligned properly - as long as the full size of the original struct is copied.

Comment: @ash Just to confirm this does not replace the malloc that I do right? I would still need to malloc that amount of space because memcpy doesnt do memory allocation.

Comment: Correct.  memcpy copies memory - you need some allocated space into which to copy it, so the malloc is necessary first.

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet the structure declaration is wrong. I think you mean a typedef of a structure instead of declaring an object of the structure.

For example

```
typedef struct Student
^^^^^^^
{
    char *name;
    int age;
    Courses *list;  //First course (node)
    struct Student *friends[];   //Flexible array memeber stores other student pointers
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} Student;
```

This call of malloc is also wrong

```
Student *oneCopy = malloc(sizeof(one) + 20*sizeof(Student*));
```

There should be

```
Student *oneCopy = malloc(sizeof( *one ) + 20*sizeof(Student*));
                                  ^^^^^
```

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be written

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Student
{
    char *name;
    int age;
//    Courses *list;  //First course (node)
    struct Student *friends[];   //Flexible array memeber stores other student pointers
} Student;

Student * shallowCopy( const Student *one, size_t friends )
{
    Student *oneCopy = malloc( sizeof( Student ) + friends * sizeof( Student * ) );

    *oneCopy = *one;

    memcpy( oneCopy->friends, one->friends, friends * sizeof( Student * ) );

    return oneCopy;
}

int main( void )
{
    Student *one = malloc( sizeof( Student ) + sizeof( Student * ) );

    one->friends[0] = malloc( sizeof( Student ) );

    one->friends[0]->age = 20;

    Student *oneCopy = shallowCopy( one, 1 );

    printf( "Age = %d\n", oneCopy->friends[0]->age );

    free( one->friends[0] );
    free( one );
    free( oneCopy );
}
```

Its output is

```
Age = 20
```

Take into account that it is desirable that the structure also contains a data member that will store the number of elements in the flexible array.:)

Comment: Might as well `memcpy` the entire struct all at once.  I believe under all circumstances, that will be the fastest, and it's the simplest to read and understand.