# GCC vs Clang copying struct flexible array member

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Consider the following code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s {
    int _;
    char str[];
} s;
s first = { 0, "abcd" };

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    s second = first;
    printf("%s\n%s\n", first.str, second.str);
}
```

When I compile this with GCC 7.2, I get:

```
$ gcc-7 -o tmp tmp.c && ./tmp
abcd
abcd
```

But when I compile this with Clang (Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)), I get the following:

```
$ clang -o tmp tmp.c && ./tmp
abcd
# Nothing here
```

Why does the output differ between the compilers? I would expect the string not to be copied, as it's a flexible array member (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423293/flexible-array-member-not-getting-copied-when-i-make-a-shallow-copy-of-a-struct)). Why does GCC actually copy it?

**Edit**

Some comments and an answer suggested this might be due to optimization. GCC may make `second` an alias of `first`, so updating `second` should disallow GCC from doing that optimization. I added the line:

```
second._ = 1;
```

But this doesn't change the output.

Comment: There's probably an optimization that prevents the copying from happening at all on gcc. It can detect it is never modified. So, in effect, it is just using "first" in both cases. Update another member of either first or second to defeat the optimization.

Comment: I think this is UB.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I agree, I'm just curious why the two compilers treat it differently.

Comment: The behavior of UB is by the compiler. Because it is undefined behavior. The behavior may be different if the compiler is different.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey I tried adding `second._ = -1;`, but still get the same (different) behavior on the two compilers.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I understand. Seriously, I get it, UB is taken to mean the compiler can do whatever it wants. I'm asking *why* the compilers choose to do it the way they do.

Comment: compiler must be even smarter than I thought.

Comment: _why the compilers choose to do it the way they do_ That is a meaningless question. That's because the compiler can choose whatever action she want.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY It is *not* a meaningless question. The compiler is a piece of code, which its authors wrote to produce machine code from a source file. I am curious why they made the decision to write it such that it produced this output. Was it an optimization choice? By-product of some other useful choice they made?

Comment: Turn up the warning level on clang and you get this *"test.c:7:16: warning: flexible array initialization is a GNU extension [-Wgnu-flexible-array-initializer]"*

Comment: @user3386109 Yep, that's about the *initialization* of the struct, not the behavior when "copying" it.

Comment: I think that it is meaningless again.

Comment: Point is that you aren't likely to get an authoritative answer based on the specification, since you've already violated the specification with your initialization. Once you start playing outside the bounds of the specification, anything goes.

Comment: This is weird: change the length of the non-standard initializer for `first.str`, and the generated assembly for `main` changes. --- @bnaecker You're probably getting a lot of argument in the comments because you have both "Which one is correct?" and "Why does GCC...?", which need entirely different approaches. I'd edit the question to focus on one or the other.

Comment: I think `s second = first;` is well-defined to not copy the FAM; and the code causes UB by reading out of bounds in trying to print `second.str`

Comment: @aschepler You're right, neither is "correct", that was not a good way to ask it.

Comment: I did some testing with gcc, and as far as I can tell, `s second = first;` copies *all* of first, even though it does *not* allocate enough space for it in `second`, resulting in a corrupted stack.  Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @M.M Actually it's the initialization of `second` which is causing the problem in gcc.  It's overwriting the stack.  See my answer which clearly demonstrates this.

Comment: @TomKarzes there can be multiple problems in a piece of code.  The biggest problem is that `s first = { 0, "abcd" };` is a constraint violation, therefore any executable generated has entirely undefined behaviour.

Comment: @M.M Actually, gcc explicitly allows this as an extension.  This is straight from the [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html)  Look for the part that says "GCC allows static initialization of flexible array members."

Comment: @TomKarzes I was talking from a Standard C perspective. Anyway, it seems that whoever designed this gcc extension didn't think to also design the behaviour for when such an extension-struct is copied by value

Comment: @M.M Yes, the behavior is bad.  I have concluded that the real problem is the assignment "second = first".  It is copying all of first, but it should only copy sizeof(s) bytes.  In fact, if the declaration and initialization of first are moved to a separate file, then it copies the correct amount and no longer corrupts the stack.  I have submitted a gcc bugzilla report for this, so we'll see what they have to say about it.

Comment: @M.M What is a "constraint violation"? I've never seen that term.

Comment: @bnaecker When a constraint is violated. See clauses 3 & 4 of the current standard for definition of terms & compliance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the real answer of what's going on with gcc.  `second` is allocated on the stack, just as you'd expect.  It is not an alias for `first`.  This is easily verified by printing their addresses.

Additionally, the declaration `s second = first;` is corrupting the stack, because (a) gcc is allocating the minimum amount of storage for `second` but (b) it is copying *all* of `first` into second, corrupting the stack.

Here is a modified version of the original code which shows this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct s {
    int _;
    char str[];
} s;
s first = { 0, "abcdefgh" };
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    char v[] = "xxxxxxxx";
    s second = first;
    printf("%p %p %p\n", (void *) v, (void *) &first, (void *) &second);
    printf("<%s> <%s> <%s>\n", v, first.str, second.str);
}
```

On my 32-bit Linux machine, with gcc, I get the following output:

```
0xbf89a303 0x804a020 0xbf89a2fc
<defgh> <abcdefgh> <abcdefgh>
```

As you can see from the addresses, `v` and `second` are on the stack, and `first` is in the data section.  Further, it is also clear that the initialization of `second` has overwritten `v` on the stack, with the result that instead of the expected `<xxxxxxxx>`, it is instead showing `<defgh>`.

This seems like a gcc bug to me.  At the very least, it should warn that the initialization of `second` will corrupt the stack, since it clearly has enough information to know this at compile time.

Edit:  I tested this some more, and obtained essentially equivalent results by splitting the declaration of `second` into:

```
s second;
second = first;
```

The real problem is the assignment.  It's copying *all* of `first`, rather than the minimal common part of the structure type, which is what I believe it should do.  In fact, if you move the static initialization of `first` into a separate file, the assignment does what it should do, `v` prints correctly, and `second.str` is undefined garbage.  This is the behavior gcc should be producing, regardless of whether the initialization of `first` is visible in the same compilation unit or not.

Comment: This is a nice analysis, thank you. If this is indeed a bug, is the expected behavior that only the leading members of a struct like this should be copied, not the trailing array? Is that part of the standard somewhere, or is it UB or implementation-defined?

Comment: Nevermind, the answer I linked in my question has what I need! Section 6.7.2.1 says only the members whose sizes are known (everything but the trailing array) is copied. This really suggests you're right, this is a GCC bug.

Answer (score 0):

So, for an answer, both compilers are behaving correctly, but the answers you are getting are undefined behavior.

GCC
Because you never modify `second` GCC is simply making `second` and alias of `first` in its lookup table. Modify second and GCC cannot make that optimization and you’ll get the same answer/crash as Clang.

Clang
Clang does not automatically apply the same optimization, it seems. So when it copies the structure, it does so correctly: It copies the single `int` and nothing else.

You were lucky that there was a zero value on the stack after your local `second` variable, terminating your unknown character string. Basically, you are using an uninitialized pointer. Were there no zero, you could have gotten a lot of garbage and a memory fault.

**The purpose of this thing is to do low-level stuff**, like implement a memory manager, etc, by casting some memory to your structure. The compiler is under no obligation to understand what you are doing; it is only under obligation to act as if you know what you are doing. If you fail to cast the structure type over memory that actually has data of that type in it, all bets are off.

**edit**
So, using [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/g/4k6Jbg) and looking at the assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "%s\n%s\n"
main:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR first[rip]
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:first+4
        lea     rdx, [rsp+16]
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp+12], eax
        xor     eax, eax
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 24
        ret
first:
        .long   0
        .string "abcd"
```

We see that GCC is, actually, doing exactly what I said with the OP’s original code: treating `second` as an alias of `first`.

**Tom Karzes** has significantly modified the code, and so is experiencing a *different* issue. What he reports does appear to be a bug; I haven’t time ATM to figure out what is really happening with his stack-corrupting assignment.

Comment: I like the points you made, especially about being lucky that the stack had a `\0` after `second`, so that the `printf` call didn't break anything. But see my edit, updating `second` doesn't change GCC's output.

Comment: That also doesn’t invalidate the optimization, since you never refer to `first` again. Remember, optimizations can be very aggressive, so long as they don’t change the behavior of your program. Make it so that neither `first` nor `second` are expendable.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Still, adding another line modifying `first` doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: You can modify things as much as you want, but until they are actually needed it means nothing. (Sometimes you have to work hard to overcome the optimizations!) Print the values, maybe?

Comment: Printing both struct members still nets me the same behavior: Clang prints nothing for `second.str`, GCC prints the same value as `first.str`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  `second` is not an alias for `first`.  You can easily verify this by looking at the addresses.  Furthermore, the initialization of `second` is corrupting the stack.

Comment: @Dúthomhas That's not the code I'm seeing with gcc.  But (1) I'm invoking gcc directly, without going through godbolt, (2) I'm not specifying -O2, (3) I'm using gcc 5.4.0, (4) I'm compiling for a 32-bit platform.  Try compiling it manually with `gcc -S file.c` and see what you get for `file.s`