# Structure wrapper and variable array size

Tags: c

I often use :

1. Array wrappers to pass array by value but the problem is that the size of array is determined at compile time (see part I of the code)
2. Array declarations that depend of a variable (see part II of the code)

How is it possible to "combine" these two types of code to have array wrappers that depends of a variable ? (see part III of the code. I know it can not work because there is a variable in structure declaration, it is just here to give an idea)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
// First part of code
// Array wrapper to pass array by value but size of array is determined at compile time
struct S {int m_array[5];} myarray={1,2,3,4,5};
struct S myarraycopy;
struct S copyarray(struct S a) { return a ;}
myarraycopy=copyarray(myarray);
for (int i=0;i<5;i++) printf("%d \n",myarraycopy.m_array[i]);

// Second part of code
// Array declaration is function of a variable n and
// so it is not determined at compile time
int n;
printf("Size : ");scanf("%d",&n);
int myarray1[n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) myarray1[i]=i;
printf("Array size %d \n",sizeof(myarray1));
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d \n",myarray1[i]);

/* How to combine the two parts above ???
int n1;
printf("Size : ");scanf("%d",&n1);
struct S1 {int m_array[n1];} myarray1;
struct S1 myarraycopy1;
struct S1 copyarray1(struct S1 a) { return a ;}
myarraycopy1=copyarray1(myarray1);*/

}
```

Comment: You can't. And just to warn you from using *flexible array member* - it is not going to work as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423293/flexible-array-member-not-getting-copied-when-i-make-a-shallow-copy-of-a-struct.

Comment: "How is it possible...". It is not possible.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was not aware of flexible array member and it seems to be very intersting. I know you warm me but I am going to try something.

Comment: @EugenSh. I tried (see my answer), it does not work but I'm still hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible to "combine" these two types of code to have array wrappers that depends of a variable ?

You cannot, at least in standard C.  In the standard's terms, the members of a structure type cannot be variably-modified. This serves the purpose that the size of a structure type is always a compile-time constant (even, technically, structure types having flexible array members).

In the general case, you have the alternative of passing your array normally, in the form of a pointer to its first element.  You may declare the function parameter as a pointer to `const` elements, so that the function cannot modify the array (at least, not without casting away the `const`ness, which you could surely persuade your compiler to warn about).

That does not serve your `copyarray()` use case, because you cannot return arrays (as such) either, nor assign to whole arrays. But `memcpy()` does that job fine without need for wrapping or passing around arrays by value, so the case seems contrived.

Answer (score -1):

I try to use flexible array member (see code below). I am not surprised that this code does not work. Indeed, the size of the flexible array is not know at compile time (cf standard 6.7.2.1 *s1=*s2;).

But, as the size of myarray1 is known ( `sizeof(S1)+n1*sizeof(int)` ), I wonder if Inline Assembly Language in the code could be used to force the copy of the whole variable myarray1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {int l;int m_array[];}S1;
void myfoo(S1 a) {
    for (int i=0;i<a.l;i++) a.m_array[i]*=10;
    printf("in myfoo\n");
    for (int i=0;i<a.l;i++) printf("%d \n",a.m_array[i]);
}

int main() {

int n1;
printf("Size : ");scanf("%d",&n1);
S1 *myarray1=malloc(sizeof(S1)+n1*sizeof(int));

myarray1->l=n1;
for (int i=0;i<n1;i++) myarray1->m_array[i]=i;

myfoo(*myarray1);
printf("in main\n");
for (int i=0;i<n1;i++) printf("%d \n",myarray1->m_array[i]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need "Inline Assembly Language". You have plain old `memcpy` for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, I know how to do that if I work with pointer to array. But the aim is to pass whole array by value and not pointer to array.

Comment: *Why* is that the aim, @Stef1611?  I'm having trouble seeing how going to extraordinary, implementation-dependent lengths to achieve passing a VLA by value would be better than choosing an approach from among the alternatives that C supports directly.

Comment: Note, too, that even with standard arrays, your `copyarray()` example is inefficient because it copies the array at least one more time than is needed: once when your array-containing structure is is passed into the function, *another* time when the local structure is returned, and quite possibly a third time when the function result is assigned to a local variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger. To answer to your question : Why is the aim ? Sometimes, I need to have a copy of an array because the function changes the element value of this array. I do the work like that : `myfoo(int *ptr) {int *localptr=malloc(...); memcpy(localprt,ptr,size); /*Do the job on localptr*/; free(localptr);}`. So I wonder, if it would be possible to do the copy by passing directly the whole array by value and not only a ptr to its first element.

Comment: My point is that you seem fixated on the pass-by-value, to the extent of suggesting mechanisms that are sure to be much more of a pain than the alternative of manually making a copy.  I appreciate that avoiding manual copying would be convenient, but not enough, IMO, to justify the *in*convenience of to arranging some means for passing VLAs by value -- which is sure to amount to the same thing anyway, at some level, because that's what pass-by-value requires.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I am not fixated at all, I just wonder if it is possible and the principal reason is "for convenience" as you said. Just a comment, when I learned C, I always used pointer to structure and I was manually making copy. Now, I prefer to pass them by value because it is more convenient and code is faster to write (OF COURSE if needed : when values have to be changed and not with very large structures).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186374/discussion-between-stef1611-and-john-bollinger).