# Function to get the Size of allocated Memory from pointer only

Tags: c

How is it possible to get the size of memory allocated knowing only the pointer name returned by malloc function ? I suppose it is possible because *free* function as only this pointer as parameter but I do not know how to do that.

```
size_t myfoo (void *ptr) {
/* some instruction to get the size : This is the question*/ }

main () {
int * ptr;
ptr=malloc(100);
printf("%ud \n",myfoo(ptr)); }
```

Comment: Yes, free obviously can or does. It's an implementation detail of the C standard library however. I suspect however that your question is a bit of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: There is no standard function defined to know this. The malloc library has an internal data structure which may/probably knows the size of each allocated chunk of memroy, but there is no standard defined for the user. It is implementation dependent.

Comment: This related question may be of interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Comment: @StoryTeller. Yes, it is a XY problem related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54082905/structure-wrapper-and-variable-array-size

Comment: And even `free()` might not know the *exact* size passed to `malloc()`, it might store the size rounded up to some arbitrary block size.